# How to convert datetime to int on pyspark

Tags: dataframe, datetime, pyspark

```
df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y%m%d")).astype('float64')
```

Provides an error of

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

How would I convert this syntax to comply with pyspark?

Comment: see [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html#pyspark-sql-functions-date-format). it's output is a string which can be casted to your required format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to format 'yyyy-MM-dd' to 'yyyyMMdd'

```
data= [
    ('2022-08-10', 1),
    ('2022-08-09', 2),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['DATE','idx'])
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- DATE: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- idx: long (nullable = true)

df = df.withColumn('DATE', regexp_replace(col('DATE'), '-', '').cast('long'))
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- DATE: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- idx: long (nullable = true)

df.show(10, False)
# +--------+---+
# |DATE    |idx|
# +--------+---+
# |20220810|1  |
# |20220809|2  |
# +--------+---+
```